# Why DistortImage function is too slow in imagemagick c++

Tags: c++, imagemagick

Hi everyone,
              I don't have any experience in imagemagick c++, But I have done the perspective distortion using DistortImage function in distort.c. But the process is too slow. can you anyone help me to fast the process. I think the process get later here,

```
 #pragma omp parallel for schedule(static,4) shared(progress,status) \
  magick_threads(image,distort_image,distort_image->rows,1)
```

Comment: What counts as "too slow", and how big is the image?

Comment: it will take more than 3 seconds. actual image size is 480x640. thanks @Mats Petersson

Comment: That does sound rather slow - how long does it take in a single thread?

Comment: actually i have to do the perspective distortion for usb camera image. camera provide 30 frames per second. but i can distort one image at 3 second. so that's why i am asking.. how can i know single thread speed.

Comment: By running with 1 instead of 4 in the `schedule(static,4)`, I think.

Comment: still i am facing the same issue

Comment: Did you compile the ImageMagick library with OpenMP support? If `-fopenmp` is not return by running `Magick++-config --cxxflags`, then you need to recompile the library.

Comment: So what result did you get from running a single thread? Same time, or slower or faster?

Comment: more slower @MatsPetersson